# backbone parse return results array

Tags: backbone.js

The restful api im calling wraps the desired payload (of models) within 'Payload'

I can ONLY get it to work this way, by 1. adding each into this.add(model) and 2. returning the array

Note: 'this' is a Backbone Collection

```
parse: function(resp, xhr) {
  var that = this;
  var ourPayload = resp.Payload;
  ourPayload.forEach( function(model) { that.add(model);} );
  return ourPayload;
},
```

In all examples I'd expect to simply do

```
parse: function(resp, xhr) {
     return resp.Payload;
}
```

The format of the rest api is "{"Success":"true", ...., "Payload":[{model},{model},{model}],  .... }

Can one explain the need to the collection.add(model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that during a Collection fetch each Model's parse will **also** be called if they are defined. And likely the model's parse function **will** be defined in just this case: the RESTful API format is using a wrapper around the payload.

Backbone docs

> After fetching a model or a collection, all defined parse functions
>   will now be run. So fetching a collection and getting back new models
>   could cause both the collection to parse the list, and then each model
>   to be parsed in turn, if you have both functions defined.

Therefore you need to define a parse as below. Note that 'Payload' is the name of your wrapper, be it payload, data, results,,

```
   // Within a collection, it will not.
   parse: function (response, xhr) {
     if (_.isObject(response.Payload)) {
         return response.Payload;
     } else {
         return response;
     }
   }
```

Now that clue came from [nikoshr in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938500/overriding-backbones-parse-function)

Further in some cases, when your [entrepid backend guy has](http://labs.thesedays.com/resources/img/jobs/nerd.png) wrapped a Model in an array then you gotta do the following with the Payload index [0]

```
   parse: function (response, xhr) {
     if (_.isObject(response.Payload)) {
         return response.Payload[0];
     } else {
         return response;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work (it should be put into the collection):

```
parse: function (response) {
    return response.Payload;        
}
```

See the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse). The Twitter Search API the doc refers to is documented [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search). The response you get has basically the same structure: you get an object, with a field containing the array of models. The same technique works well when one calls an ASMX webservice, see the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11847922/600135).

Comment: i did have that in the Collection -- as seen in the question. the problem: the model also had a parse function that was also doing the response.Payload. So in a Collection call it was bailing

Comment: @GabeRainbow Does this mean that you removed the parse function from the model and it solved your problem?

Comment: in short yes. in long, the Model parse was adapted do the case of either a Model fetch or part of a Collection fetch. using the check for 'Payload' as in   _.isObject(response.Payload